# Get rid of Visual Studio message box when building solutions with checked in setups

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I got a solution with multiple projects. Three of the projects are setup projects and they are the ones producing the error.

Each time I build the project I get multiple warnings saying "The command you are attempting cannot be completed since XXX.vdproj is under source control and is not checked out".

How can I get rid of those messageboxes?

Why isn't the warning(s) added a to the "Error list" as all other errors/warnings are?

*(Edit: checking out the setup projects will of course work, but I want to get rid of that messagebox without having to do a checkout every time)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a solution configuration in which the setup project is included in the build, and remove it from the regular Debug and Release configurations. That way you can (on a build server or in another context) build the setup when it makes sense.

Comment: Great idea. Will call it "Release but no setups" ;) If I'm not mistaken, these warnings did not exist before VS2010SP1?

Comment: @jgauffin: no clue about the warnings. Haven't used the VS setup projects in quite a few years, as I can recall.

Comment: The problem is that I have post build events that compare the configuration name with "Release" to be able to do some custom steps. Those doesn't work any more. Guess I'll disable build for setups in release mode and build them manually when needed :(